# Sum all values, ignoring the minus

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Ok so I have a mySQL table of values. Some are positive, some are negative. The negative ones have a - infront of them in the table. I'm using Codeigniter.

I need to sum them all together, but IGNORE the - before the negative values. I just want to sum the numbers, not sum them as negative numbers.

So for example, this is what it does currently:
-55 + -20 = 35

But what I want it to do is:
-55 + -20 = 75

Basically I want to sum the values only, regardless of their positive or negative type.

How can I do this? Here's my query:

```
$this->db->select_sum('vat')
     ->from('accounts')->where_in('type', 'Expenses')
     ->where('date <=', $current_period)
     ->where('date >=', $previous_period);
```

Comment: you can use "sum(abs(<column name>))"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps something like this will work:

```
$this->db->select('SUM(CASE WHEN vat >= 0 THEN vat ELSE -vat END) AS sum', false)->from('accounts')->where_in('type', 'Expenses')->where('date <=', $current_period)->where('date >=', $previous_period);
```

This should keep positive numbers in `vat` positive and convert negative numbers to positive. Note: the `false` in the `select()` statement stops CI from auto-escaping the fields.

Also, as picked up from a comment from @shubhansh, you can use MySQL's [`ABS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) method to get the absolute-value instead of the `CASE`:

```
$this->db->select('SUM(ABS(vat)) AS sum', false)->from('accounts')->where_in('type', 'Expenses')->where('date <=', $current_period)->where('date >=', $previous_period);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways.

First way: I'm pretty sure CI escapes field names, so to do it this way you need to execute normal query:

```
$this->db->query('SELECT SUM(AVG(vat)) FROM accounts WHERE ...'); // Replace ... with WHERE parameters
```

Second way: Or do two queries and sum the results:

```
$positive = $this->db->select_sum('vat')->from('accounts')->where_in('type', 'Expenses')->where('date <=', $current_period)->where('date >=', $previous_period)->where('vat >=', 0);
$negative = $this->db->select_sum('vat')->from('accounts')->where_in('type', 'Expenses')->where('date <=', $current_period)->where('date >=', $previous_period)->where('vat <', 0);
$result = $positive + abs($negative);
```

Mind that second option would take longer time to complete as those are two separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue doing a date search on a db level - best I could do was use ABS() since time_diff returns a negative value if the result is in the past. If  are working with date_diff or TIME_DIFF use this:

```
TIME(ABS(TIMEDIFF(TIME(sch_Starts), TIME("22:00:00"))))
```

it takes the possibly negative result, converts it via ABS and wrap the TIME() around that to convert back to time if u are using time specific functions like me.

Tedious perhaps but it works 100%

Answer (score -2):

You could always try:

```
where table.field NOT LIKE '%-%'
```